# Why am I getting an "Access token sent over non-HTTPS request, it has been invalidated" message?

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2.2, stack-overflow-for-teams

I've been using the [Stack Overflow for Teams API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams) for a while now, but since yesterday it stopped working for one of the Teams; that Team also wasn't listed in the Applications (`https://stackoverflow.com/users/apps/<user-id>`) section anymore.

No big deal, so I decided to regenerate the token, by visiting `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth?client_id=<client-id>&scope=read_inbox,no_expiry,write_access,private_info,access_team|stackoverflow.com/c/charcoal&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com` (where www.example.com is my OAuth2 Domain associated with the app). I got a code in the redirect, executed `curl -d "client_id=<client-id>&client_secret=<client-secret>&code=<code>&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com" -X POST https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token` and received a new access token. Yet when I use it, in the same way as before, I get an error message as response:

> {"error_message":"Access token sent over non-HTTPS request, it has been invalidated","error_name":"access_token_compromised","error_id":406}

How is this possible, since all URLs (including the API call itself) are made over HTTPS?

FWIW, calls made using regular (non-Teams) tokens still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teams API access still works for me.  Does it still fail for you?  There were [some recent hiccups](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324691/stack-exchange-ios-app-not-working).

If it still fails, reset your Client Secret and try again.

You didn't provide an MCVE.  What API route did you call, for example?

(Might be that some combination of calling [unsupported methods](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams) can sometimes lead to that error.  Note that all of `write_access` is not supported, for example.)

Comment: It seems to be related to the hiccup; when I try it again today, it works as expected.